# Signature of a tuple containing a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

For the signature of $(\sigma, n)$, where $\sigma:N\rightarrow N$ and $n\in N$.

I think you could have something like:

$$ N\times N\times N $$

but I want it to be explicit that the there's a numeric function at index 1 and a number at index 2. I also need this to express that the function is *partial*.

Do either of these work:

$$ (N\times N)\times N $$
$$ N\rightarrow N \times N $$

Is $A\rightarrow B$ the set of all bijections from elements of $A$ to $B$? I'm assuming it isn't as the notation $f: A\rightarrow B$ would be redundant ($f\in A\rightarrow B$)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ?

Comment: In your last example, $N \to N \times N$, you need at least some parentheses. Now I would read it as "functions from $N$ to $N \times N$". So you will probably want something like $(N \to N) \times N$. Also, I do not think you mean "signature of $(\sigma, n)$", but actually "arity/type/sort of $(\sigma, n)$".